# an error occurred while retrieving the list of virtual devices

Tags: macos, genymotion, mobile-devices

Through genymotion add new equipment on the MAC, click add after the mistakes, opens the agent also useless;Here is the log:

[Here's an error log.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA35h.png)
[Here's an error pic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcWew.png)

Answer (score 7):

first thing you do after starting genymotion and before adding a device you should login to your genymotion account. then you can add a device and it should retrieve the list with no problems.